# Как писать в художественном тексте названия лекарств и вакцин?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, кавычки, названия

С большой буквы? С маленькой? С большой буквы и в кавычках? С маленькой и в кавычках?

Как правильно?

Врач выписал арбидол, или "арбидол", или Арбидол, или "Арбидол"?

Сережа, если у тебя болит голова, прими но-шпу, или прими Но-шпу, или прими "Но-шпу"?

Сегодня у меня повысилось давление, так что пришлось выпить лизиноприл, или Лизиноприл, или "Лизиноприл"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, если это бренд, торговая марка лекарства, то "Арбидол" или "Лизиноприл". А если это действующее вещество, то: я выпил лизиноприл. Ну и есть всякие препараты которые (уже) не являются эксклюзивными брендами, но в тоже время это что-то более сложное, чем одно вещество: Парацетамол, Аспирин. Употребление в кавычках или без зависит от статуса препарата, это торговая марка или свободный или широко распространенный рецепт.

> "Слово Aspirin было торговой маркой Bayer, а не общим названием
> препарата; однако права Bayer на торговую марку были утрачены или
> проданы во многих странах." - автопереводчик вики.

> "Официальная торговая марка АСПИРИН с идентификационным номером 108039 зарегистрирована 15 сентября 1992 г. и опубликована 25 июля 1994 г. Заявка на регистрацию была подана 4 декабря 1991 г. Исключительное право на АСПИРИН действует до 4 декабря 2001 г." - РБК.

То есть можно писать Аспирин, а можно и, как пишет грамота, - аспирин:

> Названия лекарств и медицинских препаратов оформляются на письме так: при употреблении в качестве торговой марки названия лекарственных средств следует писать с прописной буквы в кавычках: «Агри», «Инфлювак», «Афлубин», «Фервекс»,  а в бытовом употреблении – со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: выпить фервекс, принять виагру. Также пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек некоторые названия лекарств, вошедшие в широкий обиход вследствие многолетнего употребления (валидол, анальгин, аспирин). - Грамота, вопрос № 265690

> Если официальное название лекарства употребляется с родовым словом (лекарство, препарат и т. д.), то оно пишется в кавычках с большой буквы и не склоняется: Применение препарата "Флемоксин". - Грамота, вопрос № 283425.

Кстати, официальные именования торговых марок в реестре значатся заглавными литерами, как-то: АСПИРИН (а не "Аспирин" или Аспирин).

То есть:

если имеется ввиду действующее вещество, либо обиходное, бытовое употребление названия популярного лекарства, то с маленькой буквы - аспирин;

если утратившая патент торговая марка, то с большой буквы - Аспирин;

если название лекарства, она же действующая торговая марка, то - "Арбидол";

если в реестре, например, патентов, то - АРБИДОЛ.

Вариант сточными буквами в кавычках выглядит самым сомнительным для написания).